# adobe air native extension config files

Tags: configuration, air, adobe, air-native-extension, configuration-files

I've been googling for something seemilgly simply, but I can't seem to find an answer: I am building some adobe native extension (ios/android). The native code is expecting to find a config.plist (ios) or .properties(android) file to work. The  file is expected to be in the  main res bundle (ios) or assets folder (android).

How should the adobe air app developer provide this file? Obviously I cannot package it inside the .ane file since it's app-specific...
Thanks!

Comment: update: if create an "assets" package, and change the file (just for testing) from xxx.properties to xxx.xml or xxx.jpg or xxx.plist, it DOES package it. If I rename back to xxx.properties, it does NOT package it. And even if it does package it, I find it under assets/assets and not under assets/ so I still don't know how to get  the file into the right name and place. :(

Comment: another update: if I go to project -> properties -> packaging -> android -> customize launch -> add files to package, I can add the properties file manually, but I do need to specify a full absolute path, I can't even use ${PROJECT_LOC} or relative path like src/assets/xxx.properties. If I do, during export I get the error "absolute path". Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking to the application descriptor for this sort of information. Eg info.plist additions can be added to the descriptor by adding the InfoAdditions node of the iphone section, for example:

```
<iPhone> 
    <InfoAdditions> 
        <![CDATA[ 
            <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key> 
            <string>NO</string> 
        ]]>
    </InfoAdditions>
</iPhone>
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b2-48bca492124b39ac5e2-7ffb.html

And android has the manifest additions:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions>
        <![CDATA[            
            <manifest>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

                <application>
                     <receiver ... />
                </application>

            </manifest>
        ]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

Comment: No, I am not looking to update the manifest or info.plist, I am looking to add a custom my.plist or my.properties file to the built package. These are unrelated in any way to the manifest/info.plist.. I hope it's more clear now...